# jQuery checkbox event handling

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox

I have the following:

```
<form id="myform">
   <input type="checkbox" name="check1" value="check1">
   <input type="checkbox" name="check2" value="check2">
</form>
```

How do I use jQuery to capture *any* check event occuring in `myform` and tell which checkbox was toggled (and know if it was toggled on or off)?

Answer (score 283, accepted):

```
$('#myform :checkbox').change(function() {
    // this will contain a reference to the checkbox   
    if (this.checked) {
        // the checkbox is now checked 
    } else {
        // the checkbox is now no longer checked
    }
});
```

Comment: `this` is already set to the checkbox's DOM element so `this.checked` is sufficient. You won't need to create another jQuery object for it unless you plan on manipulating it.

Comment: Just a small tip. You will get a performance boost by using input:checkbox in your selector instead of just :checkbox since the latter is translated to the universal selector *:checkbox.

Comment: Click is not anywhere close to *any* check event.

Comment: This is no way the best answer. If you have a corresponding label for your input (like `<label for='myInput'>Checkbox:</label><input id='myInput' name='myInput' type='checkbox'/>` ) and you click the label, the checkbox will be checked, but this function would NOT be called. You should use the `.change()` event

Comment: This answer does not fully provide the answer - please see Anurag's answer below, which is a MUCH more complete (and accurate) answer.  This answer is partly correct of course, but as stated, it is not the best answer.

Comment: This answer (accepted and most upvotes) is insufficient (almost wrong), because the op asked for "*any* check event" and "click" is just one - this function won't be triggered on other checkbox change events... And, of course, people are pointing out the performance impacts (as if it were seconds) of jQuery calls vs. plain JavaScript . See Anurag's answer.

Comment: I found I needed to remove the leading space on the : in my selector using the latest jQuery.

Comment: this should be inside a $( document ).ready()

Answer (score 134):

Use the change event.

```
$('#myform :checkbox').change(function() {
    // this represents the checkbox that was checked
    // do something with it
});
```

Comment: If checkbox is hidden, what to do it ?

Comment: If the checkbox is hidden, then a user won't be able to interact with it. Let me know if you meant something else.

Comment: This does not fire for `$("input[name=check1]").prop('checked', true)`. See http://jsfiddle.net/Z3E8V/2/

Comment: That is by design. Programmatically changing a DOM element's property does not trigger associated event handlers. You'll have to fire them manually.

Comment: This should be the selected answer, it covers clicking a checkbox's label

Comment: From jQuery documentation: "Because `:checkbox` is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS specification, queries using `:checkbox` cannot take advantage of the performance boost provided by the native DOM `querySelectorAll()` method. For better performance in modern browsers, use `[type="checkbox"]` instead."

Comment: Better to use `.change` because the checkbox could be altered with a space bar press if focused.

Answer (score 58):

There are several useful answers, but none seem to cover all the *latest* options. To that end all my examples also cater for the presence of matching `label` elements and also allow you to dynamically add checkboxes and see the results in a side-panel (by redirecting `console.log`).

- Listening for `click` events on `checkboxes` is *not* a good idea as that will not allow for keyboard toggling or for changes made where a matching `label` element was clicked. Always listen for the `change` event.
- Use the jQuery `:checkbox` pseudo-selector, rather than `input[type=checkbox]`. `:checkbox` is shorter and more readable.
- Use `is()` with the jQuery `:checked` pseudo-selector to test for whether a checkbox is checked. This is guaranteed to work across all browsers.

### Basic event handler attached to existing elements:

```
$('#myform :checkbox').change(function () {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        console.log($(this).val() + ' is now checked');
    } else {
        console.log($(this).val() + ' is now unchecked');
    }
});
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/u8bcggfL/2/

### Notes:

- Uses the `:checkbox` selector, which is preferable to using `input[type=checkbox]`
- This connects *only* to matching elements that exist at the time the event was registered.

---

### Delegated event handler attached to ancestor element:

Delegated event handlers are designed for situations where the elements may not yet exist (dynamically loaded or created) and is *very* useful. They *delegate* responsibility to an ancestor element (hence the term).

```
$('#myform').on('change', ':checkbox', function () {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        console.log($(this).val() + ' is now checked');
    } else {
        console.log($(this).val() + ' is now unchecked');
    }
});
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/u8bcggfL/4/

### Notes:

- This works by listening for events (in this case `change`) to bubble up to a non-changing ancestor element (in this case `#myform`).
- It *then* applies the jQuery selector (`':checkbox'` in this case) to only the elements *in the bubble chain*.
- It *then* applies the event handler function to only those matching elements that caused the event.
- Use `document` as the default to connect the delegated event handler, if nothing else is closer/convenient.
- Do not use `body` to attach delegated events as it has a bug (to do with styling) that can stop it getting mouse events.

The upshot of delegated handlers is that the matching elements only need to exist *at event time* and not when the event handler was registered. This allows for dynamically added content to generate the events.

**Q: Is it slower?**

**A:**  So long as the events are at user-interaction speeds, you do not need to worry about the *negligible* difference in speed between a delegated event handler and a directly connected handler. The benefits of delegation far outweigh any minor downside. Delegated event handlers are actually *faster to register* as they typically connect to a single matching element.

---

### Why doesn't `prop('checked', true)` fire the `change` event?

This is actually by design. If it did fire the event you would easily get into a situation of endless updates. Instead, after changing the checked property, send a change event to the same element using `trigger` (not `triggerHandler`):

e.g. without `trigger` no event occurs

```
$cb.prop('checked', !$cb.prop('checked'));
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/u8bcggfL/5/

e.g. with `trigger` the normal change event is caught

```
$cb.prop('checked', !$cb.prop('checked')).trigger('change');
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/u8bcggfL/6/

**Notes:**

- Do not use `triggerHandler` as was suggested by one user, as it will not bubble events to a *delegated* event handler.

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/u8bcggfL/8/

although it *will* work for an event handler *directly connected* to the element:

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/u8bcggfL/9/

> Events triggered with .triggerHandler() do not bubble up the DOM hierarchy; if they are not handled by the target element directly, they do nothing.

Reference: http://api.jquery.com/triggerhandler/

*If anyone has additional features they feel are not covered by this, please do suggest additions*.

Comment: I discovered the `.trigger('change')` with this answer. Thanks for this very complete answer !

Comment: +1 on the delegated event handler on children. I actually need this for some complicated dynamic code and you just saved me allot of patchy coding that is far better suited for a parent element.

Answer (score 34):

Using the new 'on' method in jQuery (1.7): http://api.jquery.com/on/

```
    $('#myform').on('change', 'input[type=checkbox]', function(e) {
        console.log(this.name+' '+this.value+' '+this.checked);

    });
```

- the event handler will live on
- will capture if the checkbox was changed by keyboard, not just click

Comment: This does not fire for `$("input[name=check1]").prop('checked', true)`. See http://jsfiddle.net/Z3E8V/2/

Comment: Just add `.triggerHandler('change');` after the `.prop` call. Then it will toggle the box AND call the event.

Comment: an alternative:        $(document).on('change','input[type="checkbox"]', function() {
            $('input[type="checkbox"]').not(this).prop('checked', false);
        });

Answer (score 6):

Acknowledging the fact that the asker specifically requested jQuery and that the answer selected is correct, it should be noted that this problem doesn't actually **need** jQuery per say.  If one desires to solve this problem without it, one can simply set the `onClick` attribute of the checkboxes that he or she wants to add additional functionality to, like so:

HTML:

```
<form id="myform">
  <input type="checkbox" name="check1" value="check1" onClick="cbChanged(this);">
  <input type="checkbox" name="check2" value="check2" onClick="cbChanged(this);">
</form>
```

javascript:

```
function cbChanged(checkboxElem) {
  if (checkboxElem.checked) {
    // Do something special
  } else {
    // Do something else
  }
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Y9f66/1/

Comment: Putting event handlers directly in the HTML works, of course.  But it it is in direct conflict with DRY and progressive enhancement methodologies.  A more accurate answer would be "You don't need jQuery to add event handlers"  and instead, using standard JS to attach the click handlers in a seperate JS file rather than putting onclick attributes in the HTML.  Doing so "works" but good coding practice dictates you should avoid it when possible (which is nearly always at this point unless you must support IE6 or something, which even MS says you shouldn't do anymore)

Answer (score 5):

```
$('#myform input:checkbox').click(
 function(e){
   alert($(this).is(':checked'))
 }
)
```

Comment: `val()` does not tell you if `checked` is `true`.

Answer (score 4):

I have try the code from first answer, it not working but I have play around and this work for me

```
$('#vip').change(function(){
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        alert('checked');
    } else {
        alert('uncheck');
    }
});
```