# jQuery click event on checkbox not working

Tags: jquery

I have the following code that I'm trying to get working.  What I want is to have the table rows with class "generator" show up if the checkbox is checked and removed if it is unchecked (default).  I have tested jquery and I know it is loading ok so that is not the issue.

The following is my code that I have tried to adapt from [jQuery checkbox event handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442322/jquery-checkbox-event-handling):

```
<script>
$('#gen_form input:checkbox').click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    // $this will contain a reference to the checkbox   
    if ($this.is(':checked')) {
        $(".generator").toggle();
    } else {
        $(".generator").toggle();
    }
});
</script>


      <?php if(isset($msg)){ echo "<span id='msg'>".$msg."</span>"; }?>
      <h2>Add CLLI</h2>
      <form method="post" id='gen_form'>
        <table class="form_table_newuser">
         <tr>
          <td class='tdl'>Generator</td><td class='tdr'><input type='checkbox' id='showGen' name='generator' /></td><td>&nbsp;</td>
         </tr>
         <tr class='generator'>
          <td class='tdl'>Start Time</td><td class='tdr'><input type='text' name='start_time' class='textbox'/></td><td>&nbsp;<span class='error'>*<?php echo $errors['start_time']; ?></span></td>
         </tr>
         <tr class='generator'>
          <td class='tdl'>End Time</td><td class='tdr'><input type='text' name='end_time' class='textbox'/></td><td>&nbsp;<span class='error'>*<?php echo $errors['end_time']; ?></span></td>
         </tr>
```

I'm still pretty new to jQuery and am learning.  Everything I have tried with the checkbox checking has failed. I can use a button and it worked (with different code), but I need to be able to use the checkbox.  I tried a few more things before posting this that say they all deal with the checkbox but none of them have done anything at all when clicking the checkbox.

Comment: Looking at this code, there's nothing wrong with it. You're probably not including the $(function or $(document).ready(function() call, or you're not including the library.

Comment: are you getting any errors in the console log?

Comment: This is your code: http://jsfiddle.net/j2YdH/ seems to work?

Comment: Yeah it's working fine Scott, check the console, also do a quick `$.fn.jQuery` in the console to see if & what version of jQuery you have

Comment: `:checkbox` is deprecated http://api.jquery.com/category/deprecated/.. you should use `[type='checkbox']` instead now..  also your checkbox has an `ID` so use that to select it

Comment: I tried changing :checkbox to [type='checkbox'] but it didn't work.  I changed it to the ID as you mentioned though and that worked as well.  Thanks all!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to wrap the function in a document ready callback, otherwise the elements don't exist at the time the handler is bound:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#gen_form input:checkbox').click(function() {
        $(".generator").toggle(); // simplifies to this
    });
});
```

Also, jQuery [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle) handles hiding/showing alternately for you.

Comment: You should pass a condition inside the toggle button to ensure which state it should be in.. ex. `$(".generator").toggle(this.checked)` true meaning show.. false meaning hide

Comment: Shows what I was missing (doc ready) and simplified it.  Thanks very much!

Comment: @wirey That shouldn't be necessary, since presumably every click will change whether or not the the box is checked (i.e. toggle its state), and calling `.toggle()` *with no parameters simply toggles the visibility of elements* (jq docs). In truth `.change()` would be a better function than `.click()` for this purpose, but it shouldn't matter in this case. So the first click hides, next click shows, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Try putting your code inside the `$(document).ready` handler, according to the structure of your markup, it sounds that you just want to select one input element, try the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#showGen').change(function(){
      $('.generator').css('display', this.checked ? 'block' : 'none');
      // or $('.generator').toggle()
  })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because the dom is not ready, your script runs before the elements exist.

If you wrap your script in jQuery's document ready like so it will work :-

```
$(function(){
  $('#gen_form input:checkbox').click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    // $this will contain a reference to the checkbox   
    if ($this.is(':checked')) {
      $(".generator").toggle();
    } else {
      $(".generator").toggle();
    }
  });
});
```

I tried it in jsFiddle and it worked

Comment: It does indeed, I didn't -1 you but I'll +1 you to at least give that back to ya.  Thanks!